# .Net Core // I can't convert from IFromFile to base array

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-core, type-conversion

## Controller

```
[HttpPost]

public JsonResult Slider_BannerEkle(ResimlerViewModel rsm)

{

            ANDWECOMResimler resimlerViewModel = new ANDWECOMResimler
            {
                 IMGFILE = rsm.IMGFILE,
                 IMGNAME = rsm.IMGNAME,
                 IMGORDER = rsm.IMGORDER,
                 IMGSTATE = rsm.IMGSTATE,
                 IMGURL = rsm.IMGURL
            };
            _uof.ResimRepository.Add(resimlerViewModel);
            _uof.Save();
    
            return Json(rsm);
          }
```

## View Model

```
public class ResimlerViewModel
{


        [Key]
    
        public Int16 IMGID { get; set; }
    
        public string IMGNAME { get; set; }
    
        public string IMGURL { get; set; }
    
        public Int16 IMGORDER { get; set; }
    
        public bool IMGSTATE { get; set; }
    
        public string IMGFILE { get; set; }
    
        public IFormFile file { get; set; }
    }
```

I'm trying to convert images to base64 but it doesn't work.I tried a few times on the controller side, but I can't use the codes I use in mvc here.

Comment: How have you tried to convert it to a base64 before?

Comment: I tried to cast to byte array first and then to base64

Comment: Byte[] bytes = File.ReadAllBytes(// FILE PATH);
String file = Convert.ToBase64String(bytes);

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Controller:

```
[HttpPost]
public string getFile(UserModel user) {
    var ms = new MemoryStream();
    user.file.CopyTo(ms);
    var fileBytes = ms.ToArray();//to byte array
    string s = Convert.ToBase64String(fileBytes);//to base64string
    return s;
}
```

View:

```
@model UserModel

<form enctype="multipart/form-data" method="post" asp-controller="Home" asp-action="getFile">
    <input asp-for="name" type="text" />
    <input asp-for="file" type="file">
    <input type="submit"/>
</form>
```

Model:

```
public class UserModel
{
    public string name { get; set; }
    public IFormFile file { get; set; }
}
```